# Recommendation of book

Tags: reference-request

I have basic knowledge on Mathematica, but not familiar with if, for other loops and conditional functions. I have to work on a project which involves developing a package something like FeynCalc.
There are so many literature available that I feel like getting lost which book to consult.
Can anyone give a book reference from where I can start learning the basic structure of Wofram language for a beginner like me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: An Elementary Introduction to the Wolfram Language by Stephen Wolfram. Available free [online](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/).

Comment: Also, [Learning Mathematica for Physics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119826/learning-mathematica-for-physics)

Comment: @Szabolcs,@Jagra, thank you for the references. I am looking through the links you are suggested.

Answer (score 1):

They don't make it easy to find but I highly recommend all portions [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VirtualBookOverview.html) that are relevant to your needs. That is an online version of The Mathematica Book. I don't think they print hard copies of it any more, but you might be able to get a used copy if you insist on reading a hard copy. After you finish with the above use [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/?source=nav) as a reference.

Comment: One problem I have with the Virtual Book is that it seems to conflate the concepts of `Mathematica` and `Wolfram Language`. Any book that recommends the use of `%` to chain computations is implicitly (or perhaps quite explicitly) talking about specific aspects of `Mathematica` notebooks rather than of the Wolfram Language in general.